# mass transit consumer not receiving message from azure service bus queue

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit

below is how I have configured mass transit to use azure service bus queue in program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    EndpointConvention.Map<IndexMessage>(new Uri($"queue:{serviceBusQueueName}"));
    x.AddConsumer<IndexConsumer>();
    x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host(serviceBusConnectinString);
        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(serviceBusQueueName, e =>
        {
            e.ConfigureConsumer<IndexConsumer>(context);
        });
    });
});
```

where serviceBusQueueName is an existing queue (not topic) on azure service bus

With above setting I am able to publish message to the queue but not consume, am I missing something in while adding mass transit to service collection?

Comment: Review the logs and make sure the bus is being started.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson I understand that Mass Transit does not work well with Service Bus Basic tier (just queues no topics), so I upgraded to standard tier to get topics as well. Now I am getting The message lock expired when trying to consume. This is how I have setup subscription endpint                      
  cfg.SubscriptionEndpoint("subscription", "topic", e =>
                {
                    e.ConfigureConsumer<IndexConsumer>(context);
                });

Comment: @ChrisPatterson increasing the lock duration to 5 mins on Azure worked but not sure why 1 minute did not work as consumer bus would throw the lock timeout within few seconds.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson Another query, how to set receive mode to read and delete?

Comment: You can't change MT's underlying behavior. If you aren't using it right, there are hours of videos on how to use it right linked from the documentation.

Comment: Ever found the root cause? I am experiencing something similar. Every now and then, the message never arrives in the topic and subscribed queues. Not sure yet what is happening and don’t know where to look.